# how to get the download url from dnf or rpmdb in python

Tags: python, rpm, dnf

I need of to get the download url from a rpm packages on fedora under python.
For example with dnf I just type:

```
# dnf download --url xterm 
rsync://fedora.tu-chemnitz.de/ftp/pub/linux/fedora/linux/releases/27/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/x/xterm-330-3.fc27.x86_64.rpm
```

I need the same thing but with python.
I have tried with "import dnf" and "import rpm" but without succeed.

Answer (score 1):

With DNF, it would look something like this (untested because writing quickly):

```
base = dnf.Base()
base.read_all_repos()
base.fill_sack()
for pkg in base.sack.query().filter(name='xterm'):
    print(pkg.remote_location())
```

You probably want to do a little more processing, like only using one of the locations if multiple exist, and maybe some error handling.

Comment: I have tried your code and looks doesn't work. I mean it returns "None". I have tried with all installed() packages but nothig is changed

Comment: ok it works, but it needs the **base.read_all_repos()** before **base.fill_sack()**

Comment: @MysticDog I edited it to match what you said. If this is the correct answer (now), please "accept" it with the checkmark.